# Extracting different Data from a txt file in python

Tags: python, file, split, extract

I have been trying to extract data from a txt file

This is the text file:

```
PARTIALRUN,0
time,2020-07-31 12:21:44
update,5.8.6.32
build,2319
comments,testing
BaseDir,\\Testing\Python\2020_07_31_12_21_44
```

I want to extract some information from the text file to get this information

```
WeekNumber= 31
5.8.6.32NUMBER2319
```

This is how I tried to do it:

```
test_array =[]
with open ('file_location', 'rt') as testfile:
    for line in testfile:
        firsthalf, secondhalf =(
            item.strip() for item in line.split(',', 1))
        date = tuple(map(int, secondhalf.split('-')))
        datetime.date(date).isocalendar()[1]
        weekNumber= "Week Number: " + str(datetime.date(date).isocalendar()[1])
        print(workWeek)
        buildnumber = secondhalf[2] + "NUMBER" + secondhalf[3]
        print(buildnumber)
```

The errors I have received:

```
>    buildnumber = secondhalf[2] + "NUMBER" + secondhalf[3]
>IndexError: string index out of range
```

and

```
>    datetime.date(date).isocalendar()[1]
>TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

I am fairly new to python so any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` to get desired numbers. For the second error, use asterisk `*` to unpack the tuple:

```
import re
from datetime import date


txt = r'''PARTIALRUN,0
time,2020-07-31 12:21:44
update,5.8.6.32
build,2319
comments,testing
BaseDir,\\Testing\Python\2020_07_31_12_21_44'''

t = re.search(r'time,([^\s]+)', txt).group(1)
t = tuple(map(int, t.split('-')))
u = re.search(r'update,(.*)', txt).group(1)
b = re.search(r'build,(.*)', txt).group(1)

print('WeekNumber= {}'.format(date(*t).isocalendar()[1]))
print('{}NUMBER{}'.format(u, b))
```

Prints:

```
WeekNumber= 31
5.8.6.32NUMBER2319
```

---

EDIT: (To read from file):

```
import re
from datetime import date


with open('file_location', 'r') as f_in:
    txt = f_in.read()

t = re.search(r'time,([^\s]+)', txt).group(1)
t = tuple(map(int, t.split('-')))
u = re.search(r'update,(.*)', txt).group(1)
b = re.search(r'build,(.*)', txt).group(1)

print('WeekNumber= {}'.format(date(*t).isocalendar()[1]))
print('{}NUMBER{}'.format(u, b))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful! I have been trying to use what you are doing but still without pasting the txt file into the code. I am trying to have the program read the txt file and extract the information. Any advice?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!